# What is the "this" referring to?

Tags: javascript, this, createjs

I am trying to use some Adobe animate generated code, but I can't use functions defined in this .js.

```
 (function (lib, img, cjs, ss) {

var p; // shortcut to reference prototypes

(lib._01AVINSTAMPED = function () {
    this.initialize(img._01AVINSTAMPED);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Bitmap();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(0, 0, 1024, 768);
```

What does this "this" refer to ?

EDIT: later call by

```
this.instance_1 = new lib._01AVINSTAMPED();
```

I've tried to console.log this and it gave me  `lib._01AVINSTAMPED {}` but I can't call anything related to this outside the .js

Comment: Why don't you `console.log()` it?

Comment: The value of `this` depends on how a function is *called* and you haven't included the code which calls `lib._01AVINSTAMPED`.

Comment: place breakpoint on this line `this.initialize(img._01AVINSTAMPED);` and you should be able inspect value.